# Closing JFrame with Q Key

Tags: java, opengl, input, jogl

I'm trying to get this window to close either by hitting the Q key on my keyboard or with a right-click on my mouse. This is what I have so far.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

      //getting the capabilities object of GL2 profile
      final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
      GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

      // The canvas
      final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
      QuestionOne l = new QuestionOne();
      glcanvas.addGLEventListener(l);
      glcanvas.setSize(400, 400);

      //creating frame
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Question1");

      //adding canvas to frame
      frame.getContentPane().add(glcanvas);

      frame.setSize(frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
      frame.setVisible(true);

      KeyAdapter listener = new KeyAdapter() {
          @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
              int id = e.getID();
              if(id == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {

              }

          }
      };

      frame.addKeyListener(listener);

   }
```

Comment: Where is your animator? https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Rudimentary_standalone_example_using_the_fixed_pipeline_by_Julien_Gouesse Rather add the key listener and the mouse listener to the canvas, call getKeyCode(): http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/alpha/main/GameKeyboardMonitor.java http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/alpha/main/GameController.java

Comment: You make a confusion between getKeyCode() and getID(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode-- You shouldn't compare the identifier of the event type with a key code.